# reactjs - Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, react, localstorage, react-hooks

Estou criando uma tabela dinamica, no qual eu salvo as informacoes da linha no localStorage. Para renderizar a tabela, dou um `getItem` no localStorage, um `setRows` na um map na variavel `rows`.

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

const rowsLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('rows')) || [];

useEffect(() => {
    setRows(rowsLS);
}, [rowsLS]);
```

Desejo que quando o usuario adicionar uma nova row, o component rederize ela tambem, e isto esta funcionando, porem o console esta retornando o seguinte erro:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Gostaria de saber o que esta causando esse erro e como evita-lo sem que mude o funcionamento

Comment: é complicado saber somente por esse trecho, mas, já existe redundância no seu código, porque você poderia passar o valor `localStorage.getItem('rows')` diretamente `const [rows, setRows] = useState(localStorage.getItem('rows') || []);` sem a necessidade de criar um constante no seu código e acho (não tem como saber exatamente) que ele reclama do `useEffect`, sendo chamado varias vezes, no caso pode tirar ele dai por enquanto com a mudança acima

Comment: Ao fazer desta maneira, se o local storage mudar a variavel vai mudar também e assim renderizar a nova coluna?

Comment: Vamos lá: assim do jeito que eu te falei ele pega a última atualização que está no `localStorage` e joga na variável de estado do componente. Ou seja, todas as atualizações em `rows` você precisa passar para o `localStorage` também para que ao entrar nesse componente também tenha sempre a ultima atualização. Então ai você pode usar o `useEffect(() => { localStorage.setItem('rows', JSON.stringify(rows)) }, [rows]);` onde ao mudar rows ele vai lá e adiciona a ultima atualização em localStorage? entendeu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom mediante ao seus comentários, você está gravando dados no `localStorage` e querendo que ao mesmo tempo que seja carregada na variável de estado do componente e quando essa variável for atualizada também o `localStorage` seja atualizado, com um exemplo minimo você consegue esse resultado:

```
function Todo () {
    // item 1
    const [rows, setRows] = 
    React.useState(
        JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('rows'))
      || 
      []
    );

    // item 2
    React.useEffect(() => {
        window
            .localStorage
            .setItem('rows', JSON.stringify(rows));
    }, [rows]);

    // botão de ação
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        setRows([...rows, Math.random()]);
    }

    return (
        <div>
          {
            rows.map((r,i) => (
                <div key={i}>{r}</div>
            ))
          }
          <button onClick={handleClick}>
            Press
          </button>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

***Functionamento***

1. Variável de estado local, `rows` precisa receber os dados contidos no `localStorage` ou se não um `array` sem dados, sendo isso a execução inicial do seu componente.
2. Precisa que todas as vezes que atualizar `rows`(com o seu método `setRows`) que no `localStorage` também seja atualizado com a nova posição ou *até qualquer tipo de atualização*, nesse caso o foco foi inserção de um item no `array`, utilize o `useEffect` com a configuração de para quando `rows` for atualizado também já atualize `localStorage`.

O problema é que você está chamando o `useEffect` várias vezes por não configurar qual variável deve ser observada e com isso excedendo o número de atualizações do estado do seu componente e acima foi corrigido tal problema.